# Android: Autostart app and load preferences

Tags: android, autostart

I have a problem with initializing my app properly after the autostart.

I've managed to get an autostart to work, after a reboot the app is shown as started but the timer's are not.
My guess is that the "onCreate" function of MyApp is not called when I call the context.startService(). The timers are set in the doActivity() function of MyApp.

I would greatly appreciate any tips on what I could be doing wrong or links to good tutorials. :)

The **manifest**:

```
    <activity android:name=".MyApp"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="MyApp_Receiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>[/syntax]
```

**MyApp_Receiver** is a BoradcastReciever with the following two functions

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Do Autostart if intent is "BOOT_COMPLETED"
    if ((intent.getAction() != null) && (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")))
    {
        // Start the service
        context.startService(new Intent(context, MyApp.class));
    }
    // Else do activity
    else
        MAIN_ACTIVITY.doActivity();
}

public static void setMainActivity(MyApp activity)
{
    MAIN_ACTIVITY = activity;
}
```

**MyApp** extends PreferenceActivity and has an onCreate() and a doActivity(), the doActivity() reads out the preferences and sets a timer depending on them.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Show preferences
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);;

    // Register Preference Click Listeners
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);


    // Prepare for one-shot alarms
    if (mIntent == null)
    {
        mIntent = new Intent(MyApp.this, MyApp_Receiver.class);
        mSender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MyApp.this,
                0, mIntent, 0);
        MyApp_Receiver.setMainActivity(this);
    }

    // Refresh and set all timers on start
    doActivity();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The timers are set in the doActivity()
>   function of MyApp.

That will never work. `MyApp` is an activity, one that will not be created until the user goes in and launches it.

Read your `SharedPreferences` in `onReceive()` and set the alarms there.

Comment: Thanks! Good to know that. :)

Trying to implement it I've come to the next problem. I add my preferences by using:
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

I can't seem to get them named so that in the onRecieve() I can read them with:
    context.getSharedPreferences("prefs_myApp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

I really want to create them from XML and not from code...

Comment: Use `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! You rock. :) Works perfectly now.
(I'd vote you up if I had enough reputation :P)